# Magento 2.4.6: Getting error "Namespace not defined properly" when compile command running

Tags: module, admin, fatal-error, setup-di-compile, magento2.4.6

When I am trying to compile, then I am getting Below error:

```
Namespace not defined properly
```

you can see proper command running here :

```
www-data@robert-php-fpm:/var/www/html$ bin/magento setup:di:compile -v
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/9 [===>------------------------]  11% < 1 sec 109.0 MiB
In FileClassScanner.php line 201:
                                                              
  [Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\InvalidFileException]  
  Namespace not defined properly                              
                                                              

Exception trace:
  at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/FileClassScanner.php:201
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\FileClassScanner->isBracedNamespace() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/FileClassScanner.php:151
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\FileClassScanner->extract() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/FileClassScanner.php:89
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\FileClassScanner->getClassName() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php:115
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->extract() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/ClassesScanner.php:87
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\Code\Reader\ClassesScanner->getList() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Operation/RepositoryGenerator.php:61
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Operation\RepositoryGenerator->doOperation() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/App/Task/Manager.php:56
 Magento\Setup\Module\Di\App\Task\Manager->process() at /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/DiCompileCommand.php:216
 Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DiCompileCommand->execute() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:298
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1040
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:301
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:116
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:171
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/html/bin/magento:23

setup:di:compile

www-data@robert-php-fpm:/var/www/html$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the `isBracedNamespace` method in the **setup/src/Magento/Setup/Module/Di/Code/Reader/FileClassScanner.php** file to replace the following code:

```
throw new InvalidFileException('Namespace not defined properly');
```

with

```
throw new InvalidFileException('Namespace not defined properly. File name: ' . $this->filename);
```

And then recompile the code, it will print the file name related to this error, then you can easily resolve the issue.

Comment: thanks for your reply , I get to know file name , can we do further more to get line no of error in a file ?

Comment: @AmitDwivedi You're welcome. You can add this code `if (is_array($token)) {
    echo PHP_EOL, "Line {$token[2]}: ", PHP_EOL;
}` before `switch ($token[0]) {` to print the line. As you have resolved your issue, could you please share with us the root cause of your issue?

Comment: The Root cause as I observed is , I defined a Constant named "NAMESPACE" inside a Api interface file, I resolved it by changing the name of the constant.

Comment: Cool, thanks for sharing @AmitDwivedi